# NavigationSplitView on iPhone: how to pop the Detail view programmatically?

Tags: swiftui

On iPhone a **NavigationSplitView** works like a **NavigationStack**, pushing the Detail view over the Sidebar view.

I would like to know how to pop the Detail view programatically.
I can't use a $path binding, that I usually use with NavigationStack.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go back the way you came.

Presumably you are using a `List` selection to go to the detail view, just like the example in the documentation.

To go back, just set the selection to `nil` or an empty array (depending on whether you support multiple selections).

For example:

```
@State private var selection: Int?

var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        List([1,2,3,4,5], id: \.self, selection: $selection) { i in
            Text("\(i)")
        }
    } detail: {
        if let selection {
            VStack {
                Text("Details of \(selection)")
                Button("Go back") {
                    self.selection = nil
                }
            }
        } else {
            ContentUnavailableView("Please select something!", systemImage: "xmark")
        }
    }
}
```

In landscape orientation of big iPhones though, the sidebar is collapsed by default. You might want to set the column visiblility to `.doubleColumn`/`.all` if you want to present the sidebar again.

```
@State private var columnVisibility = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.automatic

var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
```

```
// in button action
self.selection = nil
columnVisibility = .all
```

---

Another way of presenting a detail view is a navigation link:

```
NavigationLink("Foo") {
    FooView()
}.isDetailLink(true)
```

Detail views presented this way can be dismissed using the `dismiss` environment value.

```
struct Foo: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    // also consider passing columnVisibility down here...
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Another Destination")
            Button("Go back") {
                dismiss()
                // columnVisibility = .all
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binding to a `NavigationSplitViewColumn`, see [Collapsed split views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview#Collapsed-split-views).

Like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var preferredColumn = NavigationSplitViewColumn.sidebar

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(preferredCompactColumn: $preferredColumn) {
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                Text("sidebar")
                Button("Show detail") { preferredColumn = .detail }
            }
        } detail: {
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                Text("detail")
                Button("Show sidebar") { preferredColumn = .sidebar }
            }
        }
    }
}
```